# How do I sort a map according to another map in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary

I have two maps:

```
map< T t, int v> map1;
map< T t, int v> map2;
```

how could I sort the map2 according to the value of map1? (Or save the result to a vector?)
Is there a simply way to achive this?

Comment: Maybe you could give a small example of what behaviour you'd like sorting to have in this case?  It's a very broad term.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot sort an `std::map`. The map is *always* kept in sorted order of keys. This is an essential invariant of the data structure, and there's nothing you can do do mutate that. Best you can do is to copy the map into a different container and rearrange that one, e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::pair<T, int>> v(map1.begin(), map1.end());
```

Comment: thanks，someone told me to define a struct to combine Value1 and Value2 with key, and then use a vector to sort the struct .

Answer (score 0):

As Kerrek said, you can simply construct a `std::vector< std::pair< T, int> >` from the `begin` and `end` iterator of your map, but this will also give you the keys and values. You can use `std::transform` to only get the values:

```
std::map<int, int> m = { {1,-1}, {2,-2} };
std::vector<int> v; v.reserve(m.size());
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v), 
               [](const std::pair<const int, int>& p)
               { return p.second; });
// or
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v), 
               std::bind(&std::pair<const int, int>::second, std::placeholders::_1));
```